# LeetCode:add two numbers ----what is the digits are not stored in reverse order? what will be the difference?

Tags: python

The question is You are given two linked lists representing two non-negative numbers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

```
Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8 
class Solution:
def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
    """
    :type l1: ListNode
    :type l2: ListNode
    :rtype: ListNode
    """
    ovfv = 0
    l = ListNode(-1)
    p = l
    p1 = l1
    p2 = l2
    while p1 or p2 or ovfv:
        s = (p1.val if p1 else 0) + (p2.val if p2 else 0) + ovfv
        p.next = ListNode(s % 10)
        ovfv = s / 10
        p1 = p1.next if p1 else None
        p2 = p2.next if p2 else None
        p = p.next
    return l.next
```

Can someone tell me what will be the logic if the digit is not stored in reverse order but just normal order? how will the code look like? what will be the difference in the code? 
............................................................................